# How to pass bearer token in curl script?

Tags: linux, bash, curl, bearer-token

here is a simple curl command. however, i keep getting an error : while attempting to read the output file

command:

```
token1=$(jq .token token.json)

echo 'token =' ${token1}

curl -k \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token1}" \
        -X GET \
        "some://random/url" \
> twistcli; chmod a+x twistcli;
```

result

```
cat ./twistcli

{"err":""}
```

Comment: The `curl` command is fine. If there's a problem, it's with either the URL or the content of your `token1` variable.

Comment: yeah as @larsks points out, show us what token.json contains and link to some://random/url 's api documentation. without that, we cannot help you. i voted to close this question as `needs debugging details`, because it really does.